# value error when using Logistic Regression of sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am very new at this stuff. I need to fire Logistic Regression classifier. I entered,

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 4000, penalty = 'none')
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

and I get a value error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-8c5e74ff3477> in <module>
      1 model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 4000, penalty = 'none')
----> 2 model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1491         The SAGA solver supports both float64 and float32 bit arrays.
   1492         """
-> 1493         solver = _check_solver(self.solver, self.penalty, self.dual)
   1494 
   1495         if not isinstance(self.C, numbers.Number) or self.C < 0:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in _check_solver(solver, penalty, dual)
    455     if solver == 'liblinear' and penalty == 'none':
    456         raise ValueError(
--> 457             "penalty='none' is not supported for the liblinear solver"
    458         )
    459 

ValueError: penalty='none' is not supported for the liblinear solver
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: hello dear, as the error said `penalty='none' is not supported for the liblinear solver` so remove it and for getting better solution just add more details on your Datasets and ..

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) says

> [penalty] 'none' (not supported by the liblinear solver)

So you have to provide the penalty parameter according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer:** put correctly the `solver` and corresponding `penalty` pair. May be you need update the scikit-learn version.

```
Changed in version 0.22: The default solver changed from ‘liblinear’ to ‘lbfgs’ in 0.22.
```

And, if you have the scikit-learn version below 0.22, you have the `liblinear solver` by default.

```
solver{‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’}, default=’lbfgs’
Algorithm to use in the optimization problem.

For small datasets, ‘liblinear’ is a good choice, whereas ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ are faster for large ones.

For multiclass problems, only ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ and ‘lbfgs’ handle multinomial loss; ‘liblinear’ is limited to one-versus-rest schemes.

‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ handle L2 or no penalty

‘liblinear’ and ‘saga’ also handle L1 penalty

‘saga’ also supports ‘elasticnet’ penalty

‘liblinear’ does not support setting penalty='none'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that you can use 'l1' penalty with liblinear and not 'none'.
Also you are on a version before 0.22, your deafult is set to liblinear.